# Rundeck authentication error even added correct ssh_username and password

Tags: linux, shell, authentication, server, rundeck

Created a project into rundeck. Added nodes as ansible inventory which contain two remote nodes. Added ssh_username and password into that.
  Now got Displaying that two nodes in the "Nodes" area while show all nodes filtering.
  Created a job with node filtering (selected one remote node based on tags). Now added `mkdir /etc/test2018` as a command.
  Now run the job. But I got the error below:

```
Failed: AuthenticationFailure: Authentication failure connecting to node: "114.12.14.*". 
Make sure your resource definitions and credentials are up to date.
```

*note: I login into rundeck as admin user with default password.
Am using aws-linux servers.*

[Image: Rundeck Log Error Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwglG.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not configured access to your remote nodes. Configure the access to your remote nodes:

Check This:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOA-kWse22g

And This:

[Add a remote node in rundeck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36224912/add-a-remote-node-in-rundeck)

Comment: There you guys are using ssh keys. instead of that am using passwords. I couldn't mention passwords here.