# Rundeck 3.x error for remote execution - Failed: AuthenticationFailure: Authentication failure connecting to node. Could not authenticate

Tags: rundeck

Getting this error in the rundeck 3.x (latest) console when trying to do a remote uptime to the host in question. Can ssh into the host from the rundeck server as rundeck user and root and have set the necessary public keys there and in key storage on rundeck server.

For resources.xml properties file, what should the settings be as that is where it is discovered.

The error in the rundeck server /var/log/rundeck/service.log is:

[2020-01-21 01:15:50.826] ERROR ExecutionUtilService --- [eduler_Worker-1] Execution failed: 29 in project TestProject: [Workflow result\
: , step failures: {1=Dispatch failed on 1 nodes: [some-random-host: AuthenticationFailure: Authentication failure connecting to node: "\
some-random-host". Could not authenticate. + {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={ContextView(node:some-random-host)=BaseDataContext{{\
exec={exitCode=-1}}}, ContextView(step:1, node:some-random-host)=BaseDataContext{{exec={exitCode=-1}}}}, base=null)} ]}, Node failures: \
{some-random-host=[AuthenticationFailure: Authentication failure connecting to node: "some-random-host". Could not authenticate. + {data\
Context=MultiDataContextImpl(map={ContextView(node:some-random-host)=BaseDataContext{{exec={exitCode=-1}}}, ContextView(step:1, node:som\
e-random-host)=BaseDataContext{{exec={exitCode=-1}}}}, base=null)} ]}, status: failed]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the remote node well configured (and well referenced in your node definition), you have a good guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36262262/10426011).